# ¿ Como puedo agregar estilos a mis otras paginas ?, o sea a demás de darle estilos a la pagina principal

Tags: html5, css3, gulp-sass, bem

Deseo saber como agregar estilos a mis otras paginas que están dentro de la pagina principal, se como enlazar mi pagina principal y darle estilos, pero dentro de esa pagina tengo otras que me llevan a contacto, multimedia, sobre mí. Entonces busco poner estilos diferentes a esas otras paginas.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a que desde la página principal tienes etiquetas `<a>` que te llevan a otros archivos HTML, entonces deberías "linkar" el archivo CSS que quieras a cada página. Cada una de ellas necesitará la etiqueta `<link>` con un archivo de CSS que quieras. Por ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fichero.css" />
```

Puedes usar el mismo para todos los archivos, ya que seguramente compartirán elementos parecidos como el `<header>` o el `<footer>` o puedes crear archivos CSS aparte para estilizar esas otras páginas.